# PHP class encapsulation options

Tags: php, oop

In recent reading, I see conflicting recommendations on encapsulation methods and OOP best practices.

I am beginning development of a series of PHP classes that will be used to transport and transform data from multiple source systems to a final destination. Therefore, the properties of the first class are to contain source URL and authentication values.

Which of the following is best for a long-term project with unlimited potential for expansion?

1. Declare as public properties. Set values externally for each source when constructing class. Pro: simple. Con: No encapsulation advantage
2. Use __get and __set. Set values externally for each source. Pro: Follows OOP convention. Con: Opens all to external access; again, no encapsulation
3. Declare properties as protected. For each source system I need to work with, extend the original class and set the properties in the subclass. Pro:OOP with encapsulation. Con: more classes, and potentially files, to manage.

Currently, option 3 seems the best, despite the file overhead. I'm also open to other ideas.

References I have read for this question:

http://typicalprogrammer.com/?p=23

[Getter and Setter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4478661/getter-and-setter)

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php

[Independent getter/setter methods, or combined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6674784/php-oop-independent-getter-setter-methods-or-combined)

http://martinfowler.com/bliki/GetterEradicator.html

[Is it worth making get and set methods in OOP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10616866/is-it-worth-making-get-and-set-methods-in-oop)

Comment: **3** ... The other two choices are garbage.

Comment: Remember that inheritance breaks encapsulation, so you should use composition instead whenever possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is at least one more option: inject these parameters into the objects on construction and make them read-only "properties" through a getter. Construct objects only through a factory (you can possibly enforce this as well but I 'm not sure if there's any tangible benefit in doing so).

The factory can be configured on startup (which could be a plus), there is only one class of transport, and consumers can only view each transport's state in the manner it chooses to expose it (encapsulation).

Comment: +1 Good for you for distilling a wealth of OO and testability knowledge into a concise answer that someone with limited exposure will understand ... I'm way too lazy :)

Comment: Thank you Jon. I am returning to my studies of design patterns, and have started reading about dependency injection.

Answer (score 2):

Choice three, but you actually should make them private. (Note that there are more optioins than just the three you listed, and this isn't necessarily optimal but I don't have enough information to decide for you.) Neither of the other two options is particularly useful for developing an extensible OOP application.

Comment: +1 for suggesting `private` to avoid the "protected members break my encapsulation" pitfall.

Comment: Thank you for this. I will read more on `private` vs. `protected` in inheritance.